# Apache TomEE CMT using EJB2.1 does not rollback transaction on RemoteException

Tags: containers, rollback, managed, apache-tomee

I have an EJB in EJB2.1 spec. It is a CMT. I throw RemoteException when an exception occurs, but the transaction does not rollback. The flow I am using is calling 2 stored procedures, both having DML statements in them.

The error occurs when I call the second stored procedure, but I see that the first Stored Procedure DMLs are executed and the data persists.

The tomee.xml where I configured the datasource and transaction manager

```
<tomee>
  <Deployments dir="apps" />
<Resource id="TPDDS" type="DataSource">    
    JdbcDriver=com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver
    JdbcUrl=jdbc:JSQLConnect://dbamigratedb/database=dev1DB/ssl=mandatory
    UserName=dbuser
    Password=dbpass
    jtaManaged=true
    maxWaitTime=30000
    maxActive=100
    testOnBorrow=true
</Resource>
<TransactionManager id="myTransactionManager" type="TransactionManager">
    adler32Checksum = true
    bufferSizeKb = 32
    checksumEnabled = true
    defaultTransactionTimeout = 10 minutes
    flushSleepTime = 50 Milliseconds
    logFileDir = txlog
    logFileExt = log
    logFileName = howl
    maxBlocksPerFile = -1
    maxBuffers = 0
    maxLogFiles = 2
    minBuffers = 4
    threadsWaitingForceThreshold = -1
    txRecovery = true
</TransactionManager>
</tomee>
```

Comment: Just throwing RemoteException is not sufficient. The need was to call setRollbackOnly() on the EJBContext or SessionContext solved the problem. The transaction is getting rolled back now.
Thank you.